How do I replace a character and add another one in front of a line one line below of it?
My goal is to overwrite the / character with a - at the end of a particular line and then insert a - at the front of that line and also at the front of the line one line below it. The test I've done is using sed as below:
$ cat input | sed -E 'N;s/^(- )?(.*\n)\//- \2-/;P;D'
$ cat input | sed 'N; \#\n/# { s//\n-/; s/^/- / }; P;D'
$ cat input | sed -E 'N;s|([^\n]*\n)/|- \1-|;P;D'
$ cat input | sed -Ez 's|([^\n]*\n)/|- \1-|g'

My input:
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<b><font color="#ffffff">Lorem Ipsum</font></b>

2
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Lorem ipsum dolor sit/
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

3
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Ut sed gravida nisi.

4
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Nunc sit amet ultrices urna,/
non efficitur neque. 

5
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<b><font color="#ffffff">Cras aliquam tristique dui, viverra laoreet diam hendrerit ac.</font></b>

My expected:
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<b><font color="#ffffff">Lorem Ipsum</font></b>

2
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
- Lorem ipsum dolor sit
- amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

3
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Ut sed gravida nisi.

4
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
- Nunc sit amet ultrices urna,
- non efficitur neque. 

5
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<b><font color="#ffffff">Cras aliquam tristique dui, viverra laoreet diam hendrerit ac.</font></b>


"My goal is to overwrite the / character with a - at the end of a particular line": what line? And why don't you "overwrite the / character with a -" in your expected output?

If "the line below" also ends with a /, what do you want to do?

That's another issue, but of course I'll do some testing first when I get something like that, and will definitely ask questions if I can't find a solution.

Please edit your question, fix the error (overwrite vs. expected output), and add the missing information: how do you define "a particular line" and what do you want to do if "the line below" also ends with a /?

Do you REALLY want to remove the 1 from the start of the input when printing the output?

With GNU sed:
sed 's|/$||; T end; s/^/- /; n; s/^/- /; :end' file


s|/$||; T end: search for trailing / and replace with nothing. I switched here from s/// to s|||. If there was no successful substitution then jump to label end.


s/^/- /; n; s/^/- /;: Add leading -  to pattern space. Read next line in pattern space and add leading -  in pattern space.

See: man sed

While accepted this answer does not do what the OP asks for: "overwrite the / character with a - at the end of a particular line".

What is clear is that your way and Cyrus' way have been able to meet my targets.

This is not the only goal of StackOverflow. If somebody else encounters a similar problem they could find solutions here. But if questions and answers are not consistent they become less useful to others...

@JulyElizabeth: I didn't convert / to - because your shown and desired output didn't contain the - at the end of the line. I suggest to replace im my code s|/$|| with s|/$|-|, if you prefer the trailing -.

Since the T jumps to the end of the sed program it can be omitted as well as the label which is only referenced by the same instruction (see here). However a point to ponder is what should happen if after both substitutions the line remaining in the pattern space should also end in /?

The following assumes that "a particular line" is any line with a trailing /, and that the trailing / shall be replaced with a -. It also assumes that if two consecutive lines have a trailing /, the second shall be considered as "the line one line below" in the OP, that is, like if it had no trailing /.
With any sed:
sed '/\/$/ {s!\(.*\)/$!- \1-!; n; s/^/- /;}' input

With any awk:
awk 'flag  {flag = 0; print "- " $0; next}
     /\/$/ {flag = 1; print "- " substr($0, 1, length($0) - 1) "-"; next}
     1' input


I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<b><font color="#ffffff">Lorem Ipsum</font></b>

2
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Lorem ipsum dolor sit/
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

3
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Ut sed gravida nisi.

4
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Nunc sit amet ultrices urna,/
non efficitur neque. 

5
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<b><font color="#ffffff">Cras aliquam tristique dui, viverra laoreet diam hendrerit ac.</font></b>

then
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"}{print gensub(/([^\n]+)\/\n/, " - \\1\n - ", "g")}' file.txt

gives output
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<b><font color="#ffffff">Lorem Ipsum</font></b>

2
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit
 - amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

3
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Ut sed gravida nisi.

4
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
 - Nunc sit amet ultrices urna,
 - non efficitur neque. 

5
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<b><font color="#ffffff">Cras aliquam tristique dui, viverra laoreet diam hendrerit ac.</font></b>

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that record are separated by blank line both in input (RS) and output (ORS). Then I use gensub string function where I capture all non-newline character before / i.e. everything from start to line to / (exclusive) and do not capture / (note it has to be escaped to avoid being treated as regular expression terminator) followed by newline character, replacing it with - followed by content of captured group followed be newline and -. I do so globally, though for example given it is not strictly necessary and there at most 1 / in each record.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E 'N;s#^(- )*(.*)/\n(- )*#- \2\n- #;P;D' file

Open a 2 line window and if there is a / at the end of the first line, remove it and insert a -  at the beginning of both lines, then print/delete the first line and repeat.
N.B. I presume any existing -  at the front of a line should not be repeated.

Your question isn't clear but I think this might be what you're trying to do, using any awk:
$ awk '!NF{p=""} sub("/$",""){p="- "} {print p $0}' file
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<b><font color="#ffffff">Lorem Ipsum</font></b>

2
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
- Lorem ipsum dolor sit
- amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

3
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Ut sed gravida nisi.

4
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
- Nunc sit amet ultrices urna,
- non efficitur neque.

5
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<b><font color="#ffffff">Cras aliquam tristique dui, viverra laoreet diam hendrerit ac.</font></b>

